# Mysql require relevancy then sort by date

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search, relevance

On a classfieds ads site, I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ads WHERE MATCH (ad_title, ad_description) AGAINST ('VW gearbox')
```

That shows relevant results sorted nicely.
But I want to keep relevancy while sorting by `ad_date`. If I directly sort these by date, then it might show results at the very end, and these results are least relevant.

I need to adjust this query to limit the relevancy of results, and only then sort all by date.

I found many similar questions but I must admit I have troubles understanding the sample queries in the other questions.

I did try to append `as relevancy` but I got a MySQL error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you mean to sort by relevancy first then by date then try

```
SELECT * FROM ads WHERE MATCH (ad_title, ad_description) AGAINST ('VW gearbox')
ORDER BY MATCH (ad_title, ad_description) AGAINST ('VW gearbox') DESC, ad_date DESC
```

or limit relevance by something like this

```
SELECT * FROM ads WHERE MATCH (ad_title, ad_description) AGAINST ('VW gearbox') > 0.3 ORDER BY ad_date DESC
```

You can `SELECT *, MATCH(ad_title,ad_descriptioN) AGAINST ('VW gearbox') as relevancy FROM ads` and get a feel of the numbers and see what number to cut off your results at.

Comment: Seems right on first test, I will test a bit more before selecting an answer. Thanks.